# Serial LVDS camera interface

Tags: camera, serial, lvds

I am interested in using a camera module that is said to use a serial LVDS-camera interface. I want to use the grayscale version (VM-010-BW-LVDS) of following camera product:

[VM-010: phyCAM-S camera module, WVGA monochrome](http://www.phytec.eu/europe/products/digital-imaging/phycam-camera-modules/produktdetails/p/1401.html)

The specs regarding data format say 8 bit serial, with Y8 interface-mode. I need to get the images from this camera to my C++ code with OpenCV. I want to use this specific camera because it has an external trigger and can directly output very low resolution which is what I need.

May I ask someone to point me into the right direction where to begin with the camera? Or, rather than only pointing, I would very much appreciate an overview of a possible interface design with some notes for a very beginner in this field. I am a JavaScript developer and C++ is my hobby only so far. Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/165088/serial-lvds-camera-interface-with-raspberry-pi  Note I personally don't mind that but you should indicate this, it is inconsiderate otherwise.  With the link, someone can check the other question so they don't waste their time duplicating an answer someone already gave you somewhere else.  Also note while we don't have a policy against cross-posting here, some other SE sites do...